# Calculate sum of values for each keys in dictionary in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have a data frame something like this . One of the things I want to do get as the final outcome is a dataframe with ID and the sumof the values based on the keys.
I can get the all the keys in the App_colum by following:

```
apps = []
for index,row in sub.iterrows():
    apps+=row["App_column"].keys()
apps = list(set(apps))
```

But now I need to do sum of each key accross all the rows.
and I'm not able to crack this.ANy help will be great.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is `sub.iterrows()` especially the sub bit?

Comment: a sub is the input dataframe.

Comment: The question seems unclear. Can you give an example on what you want to sum?